Send a Rust &Path to C
I have the following struct in Rust (simplified version):
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};

pub struct MyRustStruct {
    name: String,
    version: i32,
    location: PathBuf,
    // more fields
}

impl MyRustStruct {
    pub fn new(
        name: impl Into<String>,
        version: i32,
        location: impl Into<PathBuf>
        // more fields
    ) -> Self {
        return Self {
            name: name.into(),
            version,
            location: location.into()
            // more fields
        }
    }

    pub fn get_name(&self) -> &str { return &self.name; }
    pub fn get_version(&self) -> i32 { return self.version; }
    pub fn get_location(&self) -> &Path { return &self.location; }
    // more fields
}

I would like this library to be usable outside of Rust, so I made C bindings for it:
use std::ffi::{c_char, c_int, CStr};

#[allow(non_camel_case_types)]
pub type c_size_t = usize;

#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn myrustlib_create_my_rust_struct(
    name: *const c_char,
    version: c_int,
    location: *const c_char
) -> *const MyRustStruct {
    return Box::into_raw(
        Box::new(
            MyRustStruct::new(
                CStr::from_ptr(name).to_string_lossy(),
                version,
                CStr::from_ptr(location).to_string_lossy().as_ref()
            )
        )
    );
}

#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn myrustlib_my_rust_struct_get_name(
    my_rust_struct: *const MyRustStruct,
    name: *mut *const c_char,
    length: *mut c_size_t
) {
    let name_rs = (*my_rust_struct).get_name();
    *name = name_rs.as_ptr() as *const i8; // Pass by reference, is already a string anyway
    *length = name_rs.len();
}

#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn myrustlib_my_rust_struct_get_version(
    my_rust_struct: *const MyRustStruct,
    version: *mut i32
) {
    *version = (*my_rust_struct).get_version(); // Pass by value, primitives are fine
}

#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn myrustlib_my_rust_struct_get_location(
    my_rust_struct: *const MyRustStruct,
    location: *mut *const c_char,
    length: *mut c_size_t
) {
    // This sounds like relying on a stack allocation ...
    let location_rs = (*my_rust_struct).get_location().display().to_string();
    *location = location_rs.as_ptr() as *const i8;
    *length = location_rs.len();
    // Oh no, the C side received a pointer to the Rust side's stack, which is now gone :(
}

I can't figure out a way to pass a &Path as a const char * without making an allocation, either on the stack or in a Box (which I understand for Rust objects, but feels silly for a string).
Currently I fix it by storing a String version of the field alongside the PathBuf version, which also feels silly:
pub struct MyRustStruct {
    name: String,
    version: i32,
    location: PathBuf,
    location_string: String
}

Downstream Rust projects can use the version &Path, the String version is only meant to be used for the C version.
While this does solve the problem, it feels silly, so I'm probably overlooking something. Is there a way I can hand off a &Path similar to how I can hand off a String without allocating?

hint: std::os::unix::ffi::OsStrExt::as_bytes if you only need to support *nix.

&Path is basically just a fancy &OsStr, but OsStr is not guaranteed to be encoded as UTF-8 or to match the normal encoding of your platform.

@PitaJ Thanks to your comment, I discovered location.as_os_str().as_encoded_bytes().as_ptr() as *const i8. If you could write an answer, I can accept it.

Be careful with as_encoded_bytes, especially on Windows - what you get from it is not always compatible with system APIs.

How should I handle it then? I do want my library to be cross-platform since it doesn't really have a good reason to not be. The string would be coming from the C side anyway, if using the C interface (Rust would use the Rust interface), just being stored on Rust side. Currently the only reason it would go back out to the C side is for display, but it could certainly change as the library evolves.

If it's only for display, then I would use to_str and return a null pointer if location is not representable as UTF-8. It's rare to have paths like that anyways, and if you're getting it from C in the first place, you're going through a UTF-8 string already (to_string_lossy), so you know it will always work.
